# Possible race condition with var scope singleton?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a possible race condition with an application scoped singleton. However, I thought that by defining a function level variable that this would not be a problem.

```
<!--- Calling page --->
<cfset url.UUID = createUUID() />
<cfset application.UUIDBot.displayUUID() />


<!--- UUIDbot --->
<cfcomponent>

    <cffunction name="displayUUID">

      <cfset var rc = {} />
      <cfset rc.position = url.uuid />
      <cfinclude template="displayUUID.cfm" />

    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>

<!--- displayUUID.cfm --->
<cfoutput>#rc.position#</cfoutput>
```

Is it possible that displayUUID.cfm would not display the UUID in the URL?

Comment: Trying to figure out if one can have a race condition with an application scoped singleton even if the function level variables are properly scoped.

Comment: You're breaking encapsulation by having some component deal with a URL variable. Why not pass the information you need? `application.UUIDBot.displayUUID(url.UUID)`

Comment: Al - Due to breaking encapsulation, this code could have a race condition since a function is directly accessing the URL? Is this the problem? While I understand the poor coding, is it wrong enough to cause a race condition? Aren't functions allowed to have access to all scopes during the request?

Comment: Re: *"is it wrong enough to cause a race condition?"* Well .. yes, if that is not the desired outcome ;) The fact that a function can access a certain scope, does not mean that it _should_. If doing so causes something undesirable to happen, then it is not just about best practices. It is about broken code.

Comment: Leigh - I mean is it possible to cause a race condition by accessing the URL variable from within a persistent object? Or, is it as was noted below, that CF9, but not Railo, has an issue with implicit struct notation.

Comment: @Jason - It seems unlikely. But if what you posted is not the real code, it is impossible to say anything *for certain*. There are just too many variables. As Aaron suggested, the problem is likely in code we cannot see.

Comment: I apologize for the confusing question. What I really had was some code that had an issue. So, I created the code above on the fly just for someone to say, yes, this is thread safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is going to be found in the code you have not shared, that which is included via the displayUUID.cfm file. The code within the displayUUID is not thread safe (I am guessing). That code also needs to use "var" to localize the variables--or--prefix your references with "local." to ensure they are local scopped.

**Bottom line:** When you use cfinclude within a function the included code must also be thread safe.

Comment: What if all code within the cfinclude is scoped with rc? It should be safe, right?

Comment: Correct, Jason. Prefixing everything with "rc" in this case would ensure you have local scopped all the vars in the include.

Comment: Yes. Everything seems to be working just fine now. We've had several crawls with no issues. Thanks so much. Bottom line was the bottom line. It's thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

I have read that implict struct notation itself is not thread-safe.

http://www.barneyb.com/barneyblog/2009/06/19/coldfusion-struct-literals-are-not-thread-safe-cfml-ones-are/

Try changing it to use a lock and a StructNew.

Comment: I wonder if this was changed in CF9. This could definitely be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

What you've posted there is thread safe.  The issue of thread safety with structs occurs on assignment of a previously null pointed piece of memory.  Since you're using the built in URL scope / struct which already has valid address space, this shouldn't be an issue.

You may however have issues with the logic and procedural execution timing.

That said, I do question the reasoning and design of what you have here.  It raises a lot of red flags.

cfinclude?  why?  I fear you're going down the nasty road of dynamic includes.

Comment: The code is just an experiment to verify that rc was indeed thread safe in this context. I was not sure of and could not duplicate the race condition. This is not actual code, but a very simplified  mutant representation of some simple MVC code with "UUIDbot" being a model/controller lead mutant combo.